# How to create multiple index endpoints for one Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

this seems like a simple question but I can't find the answer. I have books in my Rails app, and a scope for featured books. I want an endpoint that lists all books, and an endpoint that lists just the featured books.

I have one API Books Controller with one index action, so site.com/api/books will return all books. How do i make the second endpoint that will return just featured books? is there another way to query, like /books?featured=true ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all sorts of options here, but perhaps the best would be to define a route like this:

```
get '/books(/:featured)' => 'controller#action'
```

Then, in your controller, something like:

```
@books = params[:featured].present? ? Book.featured : Book.all
```

That's just quick-and-dirty, but certainly does the trick.

Comment: A tiny cleanup on this, you don't need to call `present?` on `params[:featured]`. If no featured param is supplied, `nil` is returned, defaulting to `Book.all`. This can also be accomplished with a guard clause which some may say is cleaner than using the ternary shorthand.

Comment: ok, i ran into a problem with this -- in routes, if i have the get '/books(/:featured)' line *above* resources :books, then i can't do books/45 to get the "show" action. If I put it below, books/featured gets a route duplicate error. Can I have both?

Answer (score 1):

untested but should work.

routes.rb

```
get "/books(/:type)" => "books#index", as: :books
```

books_controller.rb

// kinda of flexi situation, you just throw in a "filter" you want to look for.  you throw in "featured" and it will look for "featured=>true". if you throw in "published" it looks for "published=>true"

```
def index
  if params[:type].present?
      @books = Book.where(params[:type].to_sym => true)
  else
      @books = Book.all
  end  
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% =link_to("all books", books_path) %>
<% =link_to("feature_books", books_path(:featured)) %>
<% =link_to("other scoped books", books_path(:other_scope)) %>
```

Comment: Pretty cool how you changed your answer to adopt mine without crediting me. Totally fine that you tweaked yours, but you should give credit when you do.

Comment: wow... realy? whatever... all credits for you - whatever you like. maybe you saw that i also build a flexi controller for that route. before i had it pretty much static with /books or /books/:type where Book.where(featured) was loaded. just relaxx bro.

Comment: OK, I'm not trying to start an argument. I'm simply saying that your original answer, before mine was different, then you changed yours to match mine. There's nothing wrong with doing that, just give credit when you do. Also, separately, it would be worth validating the "flex" param to make sure it contains a valid attribute, otherwise, a good idea. (e.g. /books/jfklafjaklsfjaklsfjadslfkajs would cause an error)

Comment: Yours is, btw, a more complete answer than mine, so it's more valid :)

Comment: all good bro. youre right, that i changed, but it had nothing to do with your answer. actually i saw your answer after i edited my one. i just posted mine and felt like, i can do better. when we just go with route defaults, thats fine - but it doenst make sense to set a default when there is just another value so i came up with changing the paramter from defaults to present or not present and took the part to a kind of filter.

anyways, hope were cool.

Comment: @TimKretschmer How would I do it for a Create action instead. I want to have to forms, one for bulk from CSV, one for one by one item